# function is not persisting the the replacements

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a dataframe and I want to replace a string by another string. I am using this code:

```
df['text']=df['text'].map(lambda x: x.replace('%%user_article%%','a'))
df['text']=df['text'].map(lambda x: x.replace('%%company_name%%','COMPANY'))
```

and it's working just fine.

Now I want to define a function with the code above and I did:

```
 def r_tag(df):
    df=df.map(lambda x: x.replace('%%user_article%%','a').replace('%%company_name%%','COMPANY'))
    return df
```

and then `r_tag(df['text']`

The function above works but don't persist the replacements.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Problem might be you didn't assign the result back, you can do `df['text'] = r_tag(df['text'])`.

You can also use [`Series.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) with dictionary and `regex=True`

```py
d ={'%%article%%':'a', '%%company_name%%': 'COMPANY'}

df['out'] = df['text'].replace(d, regex=True)
```

```
print(df)

                                      text              out
0                   I have %%article%% car     I have a car
1                     %%article%%fter dawn       after dawn
2  D%%article%%t%%article%%Fr%%article%%me        DataFrame
3                 this is %%company_name%%  this is COMPANY
```